# Node-postgres hangs inside docker container when running in ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, node-postgres

I have an application running on several containers and I am using docker-compose to run these services inside containers. I am using NodeJS with postgresql using node-postgresql library(pg).
When I run the application in my local machine it works perfectly fine. And also when I build the application in a aws e2 ubuntu server , it builds without any error. And when I try to check the endpoints it works pretty much well. But when I try an endpoint that involves a database call, no response is received. I tried to debug the application by adding some console logs and I think the problem is with the pg library. When the code reaches pool.query it just hangs there without giving any error. I tried to console.log , try catch errors but everytime the code stops at a pool.query() and it hangs. Any idea why this is happening ? Tried for hours to find a solution online but no luck.

I found another similar issue here https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2069

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: mdillon/postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: user_data,gov_auth
      POSTGRES_USER: commhawk
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
        - postgres:/data/postgres
        - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

  rethinkdb:
    container_name: rethinkdb
    image: rethinkdb:latest
    ports:
      - "3004:8080"
      - "29015:29015"
      - "28015:28015"
    volumes: 
      - rethinkdb:/data

  user_data_service:
    build: './user_data_service'
    container_name: uds
    ports: 
      - "3002:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://commhawk:password@postgres:5432/user_data
    # volumes: 
    #   - ./user_data_service:/src
      # - container_node_modules:/src/node_modules

  gov_authority_service:
    build: './gov_authority_service'
    container_name: gov_auth
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://commhawk:password@postgres:5432/gov_auth
    # volumes:
    #   - ./gov_authority_service:/src 



  socket_service:
    build: './socket_service'
    container_name: socket
    ports: 
      - "3003:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - rethinkdb
    # volumes: 
    #   - ./socket_service:/src


  api_gateway:
    image: express-gateway:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - user_data_service
      - socket_service
      - gov_authority_service
    volumes: 
      - ./api_gateway/gateway.config.yml:/var/lib/eg/gateway.config.yml 


volumes:
  postgres:
  rethinkdb:
  # container_node_modules:
```

Simply when I run like following, it stops without any result. When I include that inside try catch, no error is shown also. No way to deubug

```
let result = await pool.query("SELECT NOW()")
console.log(result)
```

Node-postgresql connection

```
const {Pool} = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "commhawk",
  host: "postgres",
  database: "gov_auth",
  password: "password",
  port: "5432"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Tried it with connectionString also. Still no luck !!

Can provide more info if needed. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

Okay so I figured out the error. When I built it on my local machine, it is using nodejs 13 and pg 8.0.2. But when I tried to built it on my server(like 1 month after building on the local), since I am using node:latest in my Dockerfile, it pulls the latest version which is nodejs 14. Nodejs 14 is incompatible with pg 8.0.2. So that is why the local versions runs well and the server version fails.

Solutions:

1. Downgrade nodejs to 13 to use with pg 8.0.2
2. Upgrade pg to 8.0.3 to use with nodejs 14

Comment: Can you confirm that your initdb script actually runs? Have you checked that by `exec`ing into your postgres container and seeing if the schemas are created? I had a similar problem with and the cause was that the database I was trying to connect in my code was never created.

Comment: @AliTou Yeah my init scripts run. Databases are created. I can do operations with psql. I think it's an issue with pg. I tried running simple queries like SELECT NOW() and it hangs. No errors, no exceptions and no result. I spent the whole day figuring out this but still couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Is your postgres allowing connections other than localhost?

Comment: In MySQL, I had to pass an env variable like `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` to do so. But I didn't find any related env vars in Postgres' Docker Hub. Can you check the contents of `pg_hba.conf` file inside your container?

Comment: @AliTou Thanks for your help. I found the solution. See the update in the question

Comment: Ah, good to hear your problem is solved!